# Yum error in Centos

Tags: centos, yum

"Error Type: 
Error Value: File contains no section headers."

I got this error that pops up regularly. Also, when i try some yum commands as this one, i get this response :

```
[root@localhost Fitz]# yum update
```

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Error: File contains no section headers.

```
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 12
'priority=1\n'
```

It seems to be some kind of problem that looks like this one : [Getting config error for yum in CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/getting-config-error-for-yum-in-centos/190171#190171)

EDIT : my centOs-Base file :

```
priority=1

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1
```

Comment: can you check in your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo if there is [base] or [CentOS-Base] before the line priority=1 ?

Comment: @taliezin

This is what stands before that line in my centOs-Base.repo : 

`# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#

priority=1`

Seems like there is centOs-Base.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: it seems your repo is broken but paset somwehere in pastbin so we can view it. Lines starting with # are comments

Comment: @taliezin Edited my post with my CentOs-Base.repo file. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: remove first line priority=1 or comment it

Comment: @taliezin Commented it. Seems to work since 'yum update' started to work. I'll leave it this way for now on. I'll try to install some things thanks to yum and update on the case if it works or not. Anyway, a big Thank you for your help!